# TF Dataset iterator advances only once instead of twice

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I am using Tensorflow 1.4.1 and learning about the [Tensorflow Dataset API](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/datasets). In the section that describes [consuming values from an iterator](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/datasets#consuming_values_from_an_iterator), there is the following example

```
dataset1 = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(tf.random_uniform([4, 10]))
dataset2 = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((tf.random_uniform([4]), tf.random_uniform([4, 100])))
dataset3 = tf.data.Dataset.zip((dataset1, dataset2))

iterator = dataset3.make_initializable_iterator()

sess.run(iterator.initializer)
next1, (next2, next3) = iterator.get_next()
```

...with the following instructional quote:

> Note that evaluating any of `next1`, `next2`, or `next3` will advance the
>   iterator for all components. A typical consumer of an iterator will
>   include all components in a single expression.

I decided to test this behaviour by the following simple example.

```
import tensorflow as tf

dataset1 = tf.data.Dataset.range(5)
dataset2 = tf.data.Dataset.range(5)
dataset3 = tf.data.Dataset.zip((dataset1, dataset2))

iterator = dataset3.make_initializable_iterator()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(iterator.initializer)
    next1, next2 = iterator.get_next()

    A = next1
    B = next1 + next2

    while True:
        try:
            a, b = sess.run([A,B])
            print(a,b)
        except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
            print('done')
            break
```

As you can see, I am evaluating `next1` in two expressions, `A` and `B`. Based on the quote above, if the iterator indeed is advanced for every evaluation, I was expecting that the iterator advances for both of these evaluations and to see a printout containing

```
(0, 2)
(2, 6)
```

However, what I get instead is:

```
(0, 0)
(1, 2)
(2, 4)
(3, 6)
(4, 8)
```

Why is the iterator only advanced once? What would be a working example that shows the behaviour I was expecting to see?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Confusion often arises when you have an operation that mutates state (like `iterator.get_next()`) in your TensorFlow graph. The rule is fairly simple:

> Each stateful operation in a graph (that is not in a `tf.while_loop()` or `tf.cond()`) will execute exactly once per `Session.run()` call.

Applying that rule, there is only one `iterator.get_next()` op in your graph, and so the iterator will only advance once per `Session.run()` call, and the same element will be used to calculate `A` and `B`.

To get your desired behavior, you will need to create a second `iterator.get_next()` op.  Moreover, to get deterministic behavior, we will need to ensure that there are control dependencies between the two `iterator.get_next()` ops. For example, the following program exhibits your desired behavior:

```
import tensorflow as tf

dataset1 = tf.data.Dataset.range(5)
dataset2 = tf.data.Dataset.range(5)
dataset3 = tf.data.Dataset.zip((dataset1, dataset2))

iterator = dataset3.make_initializable_iterator()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(iterator.initializer)
    next1, next2 = iterator.get_next()
    A = next1

    # Get a second element from `iterator` and add a control dependency to
    # ensure that it is consumed *after* `A` is computed.
    with tf.control_dependencies([A]):
       next3, next4 = iterator.get_next()
    B = next3 + next4

    while True:
        try:
            a, b = sess.run([A,B])
            print(a,b)
        except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
            print('done')
            break
```

Comment: Thanks! So just to clarify -- I can consume all components from an iterator even in multiple different expressions, as long as all those expressions are evaluated by the same `Session.run()` call, and this will only advance the iterator one time?